# SharePoint 2013 workflow to send emails to all emails addresses in a list

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I have a workflow that will send an email when an items in a blog is set to approved. I want it to send emails to all email addresses in a custom list. How do I set the work flow to iterate over the list and make that the send to address in the workflow. I am sure I could do this in a sharepoint solution but I am not sure I want to do it server side if I do not have to.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can query the custom list using the REST API to retrieve the email addresses. Once you have the results you can add the email addresses to a collection which can be used as the send to value for email tasks.

Comment: I follow the REST api to query the list, but I am not sure what you mean by a "collection" ? A javascript collection like an array? How would I pass that back to a workflow. Sorry if I am being too dense here.